# Nested LINQ for Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Using C#, I have the following `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<MyClass, List<MyOtherClass>> myDictionary;
```

I am trying to write a LINQ query that will select every instance of `MyOtherClass` inside each key-value of my `Dictionary`. So far I have the following:

```
var whatImLookingFor = myDictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Select(y => y.myProperty == someCompareValue);
```

This compiles and runs, but `whatImLookingFor` doesn't seem to be able to be cast to a collection of `MyOtherClass` objects. If I try to it says that I am trying to convert from a `bool` to `MyOtherClass`.

Is there a special way to handle nested `LINQ` queries when dealing with `Dictionaries`?

Comment: Did you mean Where instead of Select?

Comment: You mean `Where` not `Select` right?

Answer (score 2):

You are actually selecting a bool expression from each entry. I think you mean `Where` in place of `Select` like this:

```
var whatImLookingFor = myDictionary.SelectMany(x => x.Value)
                                   .Where(y => y.myProperty == someCompareValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you're selecting a list of bools by doing that; you're effectively selecting the result of testing each value in the lists against someCompareValue, in the order that the dictionary is enumerating the key value pairs.

You can use where in place of your second select. It's a bit more verbose, but I tend to find linq of this form more maintainable when queries get more complicated:

```
    var whatImLookingFor = from kvp in myDictionary
                           from v in kvp.Value
                           where v.myProperty == someCompareValue
                           select v;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to be using `Where` rather than `Select` and don't even need the `SelectMany` - You could just write it as:

```
var whatImLookingFor = myDictionary.Values.Where(y => y.myProperty == someCompareValue);
```

Hope that helps!